# Find minimum-weight complete graph that spans a given minimum spanning tree

Tags: algorithm, graph, minimum-spanning-tree

Let *T = (V, E)* be a tree of `|V|` vertices and `|E| = |V-1|` edges, with known costs. We want to construct a minimum-weight **complete** Graph *G = (V, E')* that spans *T* as its unique minimum spanning tree.

Example: consider the following tree *T*. Edges in **red** have a given cost. Dotted edges will be added to construct a complete graph from this tree.

[image: Tree]

The minimum-weight complete graph *G* that spans *T* as its unique MST is the following:

[image: Complete Graph]

---

I am trying to find a (polynomial-time) algorithm that generates this graph. I am looking mostly for a tip, not the complete solution. So far, I have devised the following algorithm:

1) Find a cut of the graph that includes the heaviest MST edge of weight `w_max` and no other MST edges. All other edges have to be `w_max + 1`. The following pictures illustrates my idea:

[image: Cut on the heaviest MST edge]

Edges (1--2), (1--4), (4--5), (2--3) and (2--5) are included in this cut *C*. The only edge that is included in the MST is edge (2--3) and it's the heaviest edge in the MST, with `w=56`. Thus, all other edges should have `w=57`. Proof: assume the contrary; we can replace (2--3) with another edge and still keep the tree connected. Now the tree's weight is lighter, thus (2--3) doesn't belong to the MST. Contradiction.

2) Repeat for all other edges `e_i` of the MST, of weight `w_i`, in decreasing weight order. Take a cut that includes only `e_i` and no other MST edges. Any unknown non-MST edge of this cut, should have a weight of `w_i + 1`.

---

Questions:

1) Is the above algorithm correct? According to the Cut property, it should be.

2) Could I do it more efficiently? I don't have an algorithm to find cuts on the top of my head, but I don't feel this approach could be efficient.

---

*edit*: Another approach that I had in my mind was an approach based on Kruskal's algorithm:

1) Using a Union-Find, I iterate all MST edges, by ascending cost, and unify the corresponding vertices under the same component.

2) In each step, two different components are unified through an edge of cost `w`. Any other edges that form a cycle within the same (new) component should have a cost of `w+1`.

Comment: i am not able to prove it formally but it seems the kruskal method and your cut method are indirectly the same, not sure if your cut algo has a bad complexity

Comment: you are right about kruskal, it is correct and efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Answering my own question*

Here's an efficient answer I've come up with, following also the feedback from @sasha .
Suppose we would like to calculate the total weight of the complete graph G, i.e;

> Let T = (V, E) be a tree of |V| vertices and |E| = |V|-1 edges, with known weights. Calculate the total weight `w_total` of the minimum-weight complete Graph G = (V, E') that spans T as its unique minimum spanning tree.
>   NB: edge weights are natural numbers.

Algorithm:

1. Initialize a Union-Find with `|V|` singleton components.
2. Sort all edges of `T` by ascending weight. Running time: O(|V| * log|V|).
3. Iterate next edge `e = (v1,v2)` of `T`. Add its weight `w_e` to `w_total`.
4. Find `v1`'s and`v2`'s components in the Union-Find: `set1`,`set2`, containing `size1` and `size2` vertices, respectively.
5. These components will be unified. Since `G` is a complete graph, `size1 × size2` edges will be added: one edge is the MST `e` edge, all others have to be heavier than `e`, so that Kruskal's algorithm will ignore them. Thus, their minimum weight should be at least `w_e + 1`.
6. `w_total += (size1 × size2 - 1) × (w_e + 1)`.
7. Unify the two components `set1` and `set2`.
8. Repeat from step `2` for the next MST edge `e`.

Running time: O(|V| * log|V|).

---

If the problem becomes: list in detail all edges `e = (v1, v2)` of the complete graph and their weight `w`, we just have to do, between steps `6` and `7`:

```
for all vertices v1 in set1
  for all vertices v2 in set2
    create edge e = (v1, v2); ignore if edge is the MST edge
    w_e = w_mst_edge + 1
```

So the running time becomes O(|E| + |V| * log|V|) = O(|V|^2), since we have |E| = |V|*(|V|-1)/2 edges in the complete graph `G`.